# How should we think of maps to the intial object?

Tags: soft-question, category-theory

A final object in a category is one that has a unique map from any other object. An intuitive way of thinking about the final object is as the 'point'. Then
we think of maps from the 'point' to another object as probing the point structure of that object.

How about the dual?

An initial object in a category is one that has a unique map to any other object. Is there a correspondingly intuitive picture of an initial object? Perhaps as a 'copoint' - whatever that could mean. This would mean of thinking about maps to the 'copoint'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be careful with the notion of a point. If we define a point to be a morphism from the final object, then every group has just one point, which is kind of boring.

A morphism to an initial object is just a morphism from a final object in the dual category. Thus, formally, nothing new happens here. But this argument glosses over the fact that the categories of interest are not closed under duals (of course we can take the dual of any category, but I claim that often this is not an interesting one). So let us look at interesting examples.

Many "geometric" categories turn out to be [extensive](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extensive+category), and in an extensive category the initial object is [strict](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/strict+initial+object), meaning that every morphism to it is an isomorphism. Examples include $\mathsf{Set}$, $\mathsf{Top}$, $\mathsf{Man}$, $\mathsf{Sch}$, $\mathsf{Met}$, $\mathsf{Pos}$.

The other extreme are categories with a zero object. Here every object has a unique morphism to the initial object, because it is final. This applies for example to $\mathsf{Ab}$ and to $\mathsf{Rng}$ ([rngs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_%28algebra%29)).

Now look at $\mathsf{Ring}$, the category of rings (always with unit). The initial object is $\mathbb{Z}$. A homomorphism $R \to \mathbb{Z}$ is automatically surjective, hence is determined by its kernel. This is a subrng of $R$. Conversely, if $S$ is a rng, then we may consider its [unitalization](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/unitalization) $\tilde{S} \in \mathsf{Ring}$ together with the canonical homomorphism $\tilde{S} \to \mathbb{Z}$. These constructions are inverse to each other and provide an equivalence of categories $\mathsf{Ring} / \mathbb{Z} \simeq \mathsf{Rng}$.

In general, if $C$ is a category with initial object $0$, then $C/0$ has a zero object $0:= (\mathrm{id} : 0 \to 0$) and is equipped with a forgetful functor $U : C/0 \to C$ mapping $0 \mapsto 0$. If $D$ is another category with a zero object $0$ and a functor $F : D \to C$ mapping $0 \mapsto 0$, then we define $\tilde{F} : D \to C/0$ via $d \mapsto (F(d) \to F(0)=0)$. Clearly $F=U\tilde{F}$, $\tilde{F}(0)=0$ and $\tilde{F}$ is unique with this property. This shows that $C \mapsto C/0$ is right adjoint to the forgetful functor from the (meta)category of categories with a zero object (and functors preserving them) to the (meta)category of categories with an initial object (and functors preserving them).

Comment: Great! So, perhaps in algebraic categories, we could picture of the 'copoint' as selecting substructures.

Comment: that is there they become a kind of 'sub-object classifier'.

Comment: Hm. Can you mention another example (different from rings) which supports this picture?

Comment: ok, I can't :). Toposes are extensive, and this where the idea of a point as maps from the final object comes from; so 'copoints' aren't interesting here as they're just isomorphisms.

Answer (score 1):

"Intuitive picture" is usually achieved through examples. So, here you have some.

- In the category of sets, the initial object is the empty set $\emptyset$ and the unique map $\emptyset \longrightarrow S$ to every set $S$ is the inclusion.
- In the category of groups, the initical object is the group with just one element $\{ e\}$ and the unique map $\{ e\} \longrightarrow G$ to every group $G$ is the one that sends $e$ to the neutral element of $G$.
- In the category of vector spaces, the initial object is the vector space with just one vector $\{\overrightarrow{0} \}$ and the unique map $\{\overrightarrow{0} \}\longrightarrow   V$ is the one that sends $\overrightarrow{0}$ to the zero vector in $V$.

Get the (co)point?  :-)

Comment: sure; but I was thinking that points of a set are determined by maps from the final set, the singleton; the dual will be maps to the intial object; in your last two examples the point is obscured because we're actually mapping to a zero object. So we just get the unique map to a final object.

Comment: Your first example is a good one - are there any maps to the empty set? There are none. But this can't be a general feature - as the other two examples show. What I'm looking for is a 'picture' of the copoint :).

Comment: There is no "picture". In all geometric examples, initial objects are "empty", in the sense that every morphism to an initial object is an isomorphism.

Comment: Additionally, in algebraic examples, if the algebraic theory has *constants*, those must be present in every structure, i.e. in every object, in particular, the initial object must also contain those constants. In general we can say something like '**the initial object is as empty as it can be** in the given category'. Note also that this ruins the good property of the final object to '*select the points*' from any other object, e.g. in $\Bbb{Grp}$ or $\Bbb{Ring}$ the morphisms from the final object are all trivial.

Comment: @Agusti Roig: This doesn't answer the question (which is about morphisms *to* the initial object, not *from* it).

Comment: As already mentioned by Zhen Lin, as well as in my answer, every morphism to $\emptyset$ is an isomorphism. But in other categories morphisms to the initial object are more interesting.

Comment: @Berci: You mean rings without unit.